# Issue with move_uploaded_file

Tags: php, file-upload

i have a problem with my PHP code below, it won't run my move_uploaded_file correctly. Therefore it'll always use `header("Location: /Chat/?upmovfailed=4&upmov=1");` instead of moving the file and going to `header("Location: /?success=1");`. when i try to echo `$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]` i get a blank

```
session_start();

$target_dir = "uploadedbyuser/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$time = time();
$newname = $_SESSION['user'].'u'.$time;
$targetuploadname = $target_dir . $newname;
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

if(isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
    if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000000) {
        header("Location: /Chat/?upmovfailed=1&upmov=1");
        die("");
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    if($imageFileType != "mp4") {
        header("Location: /Chat/?upmovfailed=2&upmov=1");
        die("");
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    if ($uploadOk == 0) {
        header("Location: /Chat/?upmovfailed=3&upmov=1");
        die("");
    } else {
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $targetuploadname .'.'.$imageFileType )) {
            header("Location: /?success=1");
        } else {
            header("Location: /Chat/?upmovfailed=4&upmov=1");
            die("");
        }
    }
} else {
    header("Location: /Chat/?upmov=1");
    die("");
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide the echo from die()?

Comment: `$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]` is empty while i've got a `<input type="file">` with name fileToUpload.

Comment: does your `<form>` looks like this <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">`?`

Comment: `<form style="display: inline; margin-right: 2%;" action="/uploadmovie.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" class="custom-file-input" style="outline: 0; margin-bottom: 15px;" required />
       <br />
       <input class="submitimage" type="submit" name="submit" value="Uploaden" />
      </form>` this is the form

Comment: ok. maybe your php.ini is in the way. check `file_uploads`, `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size`

Comment: Yes that worked. Thanks! I still had my upload_max_filesize on 2M. If you place a answer i'll be able to accept it.

Comment: I did place an answer. Your welcome ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for those who have problems with `move_uploaded_file()`. Check if your `<form>` has the attributes `method="POST"` and `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. If it still fails, check your [php.ini](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php) settings. The important parts are `file_uploads`, `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size`. If you under linux also make sure you have set the right permissions for your upload-directory.